# Unable to display mathematical equation using mathview in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android app in which I need to display mathematical equations in my app. I have decided to use kexanie mathview library as suggested on stackoverflow but I am not able to understand how to use it.
There was an example given on github and when I copy pasted the code given below. it displays "Webview" instead of the mathematical equation.

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/formula_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    auto:text="When \\(a \\ne 0\\), there are two solutions to \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\)
    and they are $$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$"
    auto:engine="MathJax"
    >
</io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies to `build.gradle` file :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
}
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView).

Comment: If u have experience, can you please tell me the using an example code how to display a maths formula in android app.

Answer (score 0):

```
What namespace you are importing for "Auto".  
   it should be "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  I tested it and 
   it is working fine.
```

Tyr with the second example given:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MathView formula_two;
String tex = "This come from string. You can insert inline formula:" +
        " \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\) " +
        "or displayed formula: $$\\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    formula_two = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula_two);
    formula_two.setText(tex);
}
  }
```

XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/formula_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    auto:engine="KaTeX"
    >
</io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>l
```

Comment: Actually in the design view in xml it shows "Webview", but in the emulator it works fine. I hadnt earlier tried in the emulator.